# Spherical building at infinity for $SL(n, \mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, reductive-groups, buildings

Is there somewhere I can read about the spherical building at infinity for $SL(n, \mathbb{Q}_p)$?

I'm looking for something with lots of explicit examples and computations.  (I have books on the general theory, but these are hard for me to parse)

Comment: The spherical building itself is just a projective space, which is easy to understand. What exactly is it you would like to know?

Comment: For example, for SL(3, Q_2), I know I need to glue together copies of the Heawood graph.   Where can I find explicit examples/ computations like this for SL(n,Q_p) for other values of p and n?

Comment: I still don't completely understand the analogy with projective space

Answer (score 4):

For a treatment of buildings with examples (not only for the spherical building, but for other notions as well) I recommand :

Abramenko, Brown, Buildings, Theory and applications, GTM 248, Springer 2008

Dasgupta, Teitelbaum, The $p$-adic upper half plane, in $p$-adic geometry, Lect Ser. 45, AMS, 2008 (for the case of ${\rm SL}(2)$)

Garrett, Buildings and classical groups, Chapman & Hall, 1997.

Ronan, Buildings: main ideas and applications. I Main ideas Bull LMS 1992

Ronan, Buildings: main ideas and applications. II Arithmetic groups, buildings and symmetric spaces,  Bull LMS 1992